# calculate mod using pow function python

Tags: python, pow

So, If i would like to calculate the value of 6^8 mod 5 using the pow function, what should I put in a line??

In the assumption that You don't need to import it first

I know that pow is used like pow (x, y) = pow (6, 8) = 6^8
and

My guess is

```
mod.pow(6,8)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Two way, `pow(x, y)` or `x**y`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's simple: `pow` takes an optional 3rd argument for the modulus.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow):

> `pow(x, y[, z])`
>
> Return x to the power y; if z is present, return x to the power y, modulo z (computed more efficiently than `pow(x, y) % z)`. The
>   two-argument form pow(x, y) is equivalent to using the power operator:
>   `x**y`.

So you want:

```
pow(6, 8, 5)
```

Not only is `pow(x, y, z)` faster & more efficient than `(x ** y) % z` it can easily handle large values of `y` without using arbitrary precision arithmetic, assuming `z` is a simple machine integer.

Comment: Note that in version 3.8+: For int operands, the three-argument form of pow now allows the second argument to be negative, permitting computation of modular inverses. And keyword arguments are now permitted. Formerly, only positional arguments were supported.

Comment: Thank you so much! With your help I managed to calculate pow(3, 545918790 // 3, 10**9+7) just in time.

Comment: speed tested and found false. it is slower than `(x**y)%z`

Comment: @ishandutta2007 Try it with smallish `x` and `z` (say, under 30 million) and large `y`.

Comment: small cases don't mean much to me. Time complexity is more dominated by the large case. If someone is using in a application where there are small cases only  this might suffice but someone like me who needs coverage about large cases as well including arbitrary precision (ie beyond 128 bits), this wont.

Comment: @ishandutta2007 But if x and y are large `(x ** y)` will cause a MemoryError, so you can't use that approach for arbitrary precision (eg, RSA calculations).

Comment: I don't remember what value I tested it with, but it was a moderate value not very large and I found `pow` is slower than `**`. My point is `pow` should handle all those cases internally and return the optimized result no matter what the user calls it with at least till python3.8 it is not so. Hopefully Guido van Rossum is reading this comment.

Comment: @ishandutta2007 Perhaps, although the extra code needed to make that decision could make pow slower for the common case when the args are fairly small. I should mention that there's also a small overhead in making a function call vs invoking an operator. Fortunately, built-in functions (and many stdlib functions) are coded in C, and the overhead in calling a C function is not as bad as the overhead in calling a function coded in Python. (And of course a C function also executes faster than an equivalent Python function).

Comment: FWIW, `**` isn't as good as it could be, either. Eg, for positive integer `n`, `1<<n` is faster than `2**n`.

Answer (score 8):

check the docs of [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow):

```
pow(6, 8, 5)
```

does what you want.

do *not* use `a ** b % n`! while this will give the correct result it will be by orders of magnitude slower if you do calculations for bigger numbers. `pow` will do the modulo operation in every step while `**` will first do the exponentiation in the integers (which may result in a *huge* number) and take the modulus only at the end.

now if you are interested in numbers that are bigger than 32 bit you may want to have a look at [gmpy2](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for even more speed.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning gmpy2. Another arbitrary precision package worth looking at is [mpmath](http://mpmath.org), if you want fancy functions, root solving, integrals, etc. FWIW, mpmath will use gmpy, if it's available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '%' character to get the modulo value. For example `print(pow(6,8) % 5)` or `print(6**8 % 5)`.